# Unable to understand this Python command

Tags: python

```
if 'example' in resp:
```

What does the above command mean, what is `in resp:`?

I'm going through publicly released source codes, to get a better understand on python before I go into creating programs, however I just don't understand or am able to find what " in resp: " is/means..

The exact code was

```
if 'example' in resp:
   print 'Success'
```

Comment: 'resp' is a variable and ':' indicates start of a block(if block in this example) so basically the it is evaluating if string 'example' is present in 'resp' variable

Answer (score 1):

The expression

```
'example' in resp
```

Evaluates to `True` if the variable `resp` contains the value `'example'` and `False` otherwise. Obviously this only works if `resp` is of a type that contains multiple values, such a list, a set, a string, or a tuple. This is equivalent to calling:

```
resp.__contains__('example')
```

Here are a few examples:

```
1 in [1, 2, 3, 4] #evaluates to true because the value 1 is found in the list [1, 2, 3, 4]

'a' in "abc" #evaluates to true because the character 'a' is found within the string "abc"

0 in {5, 6, 7} #evaluates to false because the value of 0 is not found within the set {5, 6, 7}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [Expressions - Comparisons](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#in):

> The operators `in` and `not in` test for collection membership. x in s
>   evaluates to true if x is a member of the collection s, and false
>   otherwise. x not in s returns the negation of x in s. The collection
>   membership test has traditionally been bound to sequences; an object
>   is a member of a collection if the collection is a sequence and
>   contains an element equal to that object. However, it make sense for
>   many other object types to support membership tests without being a
>   sequence. In particular, dictionaries (for keys) and sets support
>   membership testing.
>
> For the list and tuple types, x in y is true if and only if there
>   exists an index i such that x == y[i] is true.
>
> **For the Unicode and string types, x in y is true if and only if x is a
>   substring of y.** An equivalent test is y.find(x) != -1. Note, x and y
>   need not be the same type; consequently, u'ab' in 'abc' will return
>   True. Empty strings are always considered to be a substring of any
>   other string, so "" in "abc" will return True.

Comment: +1 for link to documentation, which is always the good place to look at!

Answer (score 0):

Internally it calls [`resp.__contains__('example')`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__). Usually this checks if a collection contains a certain element.

Answer (score 0):

The `in` operator tests containment. Depending on the type of `resp`, that could be any of several different things.

If `resp` is a string, this tests whether `'example'` is a substring of `resp`:

```
>>> 'example' in 'example4'
True
>>> 'example' in 'sample'
False
```

If `resp` is a list, set, tuple, or other collection, this tests whether `'example'` is in the collection:

```
>>> 'example' in ['example', 'asdf']
True
>>> 'example' in ['example4', 'asdf']
False
```

If `resp` is a dict, this tests whether `'example'` is a key in the dict:

```
>>> 'example' in {'example': 'asdf'}
True
>>> 'example' in {'asdf': 'example'}
False
```

If `resp` is of some other type, this does whatever the type of `resp` says `in` does. You can expect it to be something in the spirit of the above examples, but it could do something crazy like run Quake or download porn if that's what the `__contains__` method of `resp` says to do.